# Silex framework: using both OAuth and Basic authentication

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, silex

in my current Silex project I would like to realize a login via Oauth and basic login both. For OAuth, I am using a Silex extension (https://github.com/gigablah/silex-oauth). Unfortunately, now I have problems with integrating the basic login.
My thoughts are that I have to create a custom user provider which provides both OAuth and password via DB, but I don't know how to realize it really.

At this point, I have a really ugly mixture of two User providers. For me, it is logic, but it will not work. I think I am off the track, so it would be really nice, if you can give me some tips - I am trying it for a few days now...

My user provider:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
private $conn;
private $oauth;

public function __construct($oauth = null)
{
    global $app;
    if($oauth) { $this->oauth = $oauth; }
    $this->conn = $app['db'];
}


/*public function loadAllUsers()
{
    $users = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users')->fetchAll();
    $users_object = array();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (!empty($user['username'])) {
            $users_object[$user['username']] =  array($user['password'], $user['firstname'], $user['lastname'], explode(',', $user['roles']));
        }
    }  
    $oauth = (array)$this->oauth;
    print_r($oauth->users);
    if (count($oauth['users']) > 0 ) {
                print_r($this->oauth);
    }

    if ($this->oauth) {
        if (count($oauth['users'])) {
            return $this->oauth;
        } else { 
    }     return $users_object;
        } else {
        return $users_object;
    }
}*/



public function loadUserByOAuthCredentials($token)
{
    return $this->oauth->loadUserByOAuthCredentials($token);
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    if ($this->oauth->loadUserByUsername($username)) {
        return $this->oauth->loadUserByUsername($username);
    } else {
    $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', array(strtolower($username)));
    if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
    }


        return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
    }
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
    }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

   public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, if you need more info, please tell me.
thoras

Comment: In Silex apps I've used both simple and OAuth providers, but not at the same time. In Symfony you can define a special provider of type "chain" that looks for users in all the configured providers: if the user is not found in the first providers, it looks for in the second one and so on. See details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html This technique should also work for Silex (I haven't tried) and it would save you from doing all that manually.

Comment: As a side note you should probably **not** pass the `$app` container around as a global variable.